# Assigning different streams to `srcObject` of a video element

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I have a `video` element.  I have multiple `streams` captured by `navigator.getUserMedia`.

I can assign `srcObject` successfully the first time:

```
previewVideoElement.srcObject = stream;
```

However if I re-assign a different stream to `srcObject` later (same element) then the stream doesn't work (no errors, blank video).  How can I do this without recreating video elements each time?

Edit: trying this fails as well:

```
const previewVideoElement = document.getElementById("new-device-preview");
previewVideoElement.pause();
previewVideoElement.srcObject = stream;
previewVideoElement.play();
```

Edit: calling this works a few times, but then fails with `The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()`.  Without `pause` I get `The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.`.

```
previewVideoElement.pause();
previewVideoElement.srcObject = stream;
previewVideoElement.load();
previewVideoElement.play();
```

Edit:  even this heap of garbage doesn't work:

```
const previewVideoElement = document.getElementById("new-device-preview");
//previewVideoElement.pause();
previewVideoElement.srcObject = stream;
previewVideoElement.load();
const isPlaying = previewVideoElement.currentTime > 0 && !previewVideoElement.paused && !previewVideoElement.ended && previewVideoElement.readyState > 2;
if (!isPlaying)
    setTimeout(function () {
         previewVideoElement.play();
    }, 500);
```

The only thing I could get working reliably:

```
var previewVideoElement = document.getElementById("new-device-preview");
if (previewVideoElement.srcObject) {
      $("#new-device-preview-container").empty();
      $("#new-device-preview-container").html('<video autoplay class="new-device-preview" id="new-device-preview"></video>')
}
previewVideoElement = document.getElementById("new-device-preview");
previewVideoElement.srcObject = stream;
```

Comment: Did you try stopping and playing the video after changing the source.

Comment: @adeneo Just tried that - it works the first time but then fails after.

Comment: Maybe you should reload it? I'll post something.

Comment: Is this with Chrome? Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: [Wfm](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/9p7zpw0e/).